# Accessing Api response in XML format in Deluge

Tags: xml-parsing, openapi, deluge

I am using an open APi

> https://jobstream.api.jobtechdev.se/feed?date=2023-05-02T08%3A08%3A44&updated-before-date=2023-05-02T08%3A10%3A44

The response is in XML format.I need to extract the id  & title.

I have used the webhook.

```
response = invokeurl
[
url :"https://jobstream.api.jobtechdev.se/feed?date=2023-05-02T08%3A08%3A44&updated-before-date=2023-05-02T08%3A10%3A44"
    type :GET
];

info response;
BUT instead of getting the xml responsei, I get this:

1683018364187.atom+xml
Function executed successfully
```

I have also tried using toXml function, but it gives same result.